# Problem in chrome extension manifest v2 hostname in manifest permissions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am trying to `chrome.cookies.getAll` in the background script with manifest V2:

```
{
  "background": {...},
  "browser_action": {...},
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "storage",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://*.abc.com/"
  ],
}
```

But I get following error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: No host permissions for cookies at url: "http://.abc.com/".
```

It runs perfectly fine if I change the host to `"*://*/"` in the manifest permissions, like this:

```
{
  "background": {...},
  "browser_action": {...},
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "storage",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://*/"
  ],
}
```

I don't want to keep it open and I want to restrict it to `abc.com`. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Assuming the domain names are really identical in manifest.json and getAll, it looks like a bug in Chrome. Note though, in modern Chrome to get cookies for a domain, you must use [domain](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-getAll) property in getAll instead of prefixing the URL with a dot.

Comment: My getAll looks like this: `chrome.cookies.getAll({ domain: '.abc.com' }, (cookies) => {})` . I can't find the reason why it itsn't working

Comment: I guess this is an invalid domain because of the leading dot. Try removing it.

Comment: Ok. I tried this now. No luck. :( @wOxxOm

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Chrome because it works fine in Firefox.

Comment: Can you try, in manifest `"permissions"` to use match pattern `*://*.abc.com/*` (with asterisk at the end)?